# WPF padding with StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I pad a string in wpf by means of StringFormat?
I'm using a multibinding:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Name: {0}, age: {1}">
    <Binding Path="Name"/>
    <Binding Path="Age"/>
 </MultiBinding>
```

Is there any way to pad the string such that column Age begins at position 50 for instance? I am looking for something that is similar to

```
string.PadLeft(50)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to pad your value in the string format like this:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Name: {0}, age: {1,50}">
    <Binding Path="Name"/>
    <Binding Path="Age"/>
 </MultiBinding>
```

However, you should note that your request is *not* how padding works. Instead of starting at position 50, the `Age` value will be padded with 50 spaces *after* the `Name` value.

There is no way that I am aware of that will enforce an exact starting position for your `Age` value when it is in a `MultiBinding`, unless it is the first value to be data bound. Also, this will only pad the actual value and not the `age` text.

Answer (score 2):

Other way may be to use `Converter`:

```
public class PaddingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name = values[0] as string;
        string age = values[1] as string;
        var text = String.Format("Name: {0}, age: {1}", name, age);
        return text.PadLeft(Width);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and your xaml:

```
<local:PaddingConverter x:Key="PaddingConverter" Width="50"/>
<MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource PaddingConverter}>
    <Binding Path="Name"/>
    <Binding Path="Age"/>
</MultiBinding>
```